VertexAI generateContent produces unexpected token DOCTYPE error
It's my first vertexAI node code. I referred the samples in google documentation.
I'm running this in my windows glcoud cli. The same query works fine when I curl generateContent, but not when written using node.
This is the error:
undefined:1
<!DOCTYPE html>
^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<', "<!DOCTYPE "... is not valid JSON
.
.
.
    at async throwErrorIfNotOK (C:\code\node\node_modules\@google-cloud\vertexai\build\src\functions\post_fetch_processing.js:29:27)
    at async generateContent (C:\code\node\node_modules\@google-cloud\vertexai\build\src\functions\generate_content.js:58:5)
    at async run (C:\code\node\testvert.js:19:15)

Node.js v22.9.0

Here's the relevant snippet:

    const {
        VertexAI
    } = require('@google-cloud/vertexai');
    
    const vertexAI = new VertexAI({project: PROJECT_NAME, location: 'asia-south1-a'});
    
    // Instantiate Gemini models
    const jdGenerativeModel = vertexAI.getGenerativeModel({model: 'gemini-1.0-pro'});
    
    async function run(jobDesc) {
        let command = "What is the capital of India?";
        let request = {
            contents: [{role: 'user', parts: command}]
        };
        let result = await jdGenerativeModel.generateContent(command);
        let response = await result.json();
        console.log(response);
    };
    
    run();

The error points to this line: jdGenerativeModel.generateContent(command);
I've tried cutting down all the unnecessary lines in the original code, down to bare bones.
Uninstalled google cloud, restarted and reinstalled.

Errors of this type strongly suggests that your endpoint is incorrect and that your code is (unexpectedly) receiving HTML (beginning <!DOCTYPE) in the response. Check your endpoint.

localtion should be a region not a zone (see generateContent

Thank you @DazWilkin - changing the location helped. I now have a permission denied error, which is a different problem. It also explains why curl worked (because key is present in the url). For node library, I've to create proper service account, permissions, auth etc.

    const {VertexAI} = require('@google-cloud/vertexai');
    const vertex_ai = new VertexAI({project: PROJECT_NAME, location: 'asia-south1-a'});
    const model = 'gemini-1.0-pro';


    const generativeModel = vertex_ai.preview.getGenerativeModel({
  model: model,
  generationConfig: {
    'maxOutputTokens': 8192,
    'temperature': 1,
    'topP': 0.95,
  },
  safetySettings: [
    {
      'category': 'HARM_CATEGORY_HATE_SPEECH',
      'threshold': 'OFF',
    },
    {
      'category': 'HARM_CATEGORY_DANGEROUS_CONTENT',
      'threshold': 'OFF',
    },
    {
      'category': 'HARM_CATEGORY_SEXUALLY_EXPLICIT',
      'threshold': 'OFF',
    },
    {
      'category': 'HARM_CATEGORY_HARASSMENT',
      'threshold': 'OFF',
    }
  ],
});


    async function generateContent() {
  const req = {
    contents: [
      {role: 'user', parts: [{text: `What is the capital of India?`}]}
    ],
  };

  const streamingResp = await generativeModel.generateContentStream(req);

  for await (const item of streamingResp.stream) {
    process.stdout.write('stream chunk: ' + JSON.stringify(item) + '\n');
  }

    process.stdout.write('aggregated response: ' + JSON.stringify(await streamingResp.response));
}

    generateContent();

